# With two <form>'s on a page, how to you make jQuery only run the functions on one (without using IDs)?

Tags: jquery

Now I know this sounds elementary, but I honestly can't dial this in. I have two forms on a single page. I wrote some form validating functions that are triggered as such:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkRequired();
    checkLengths();
    checkFormats();
    checkErrors();
});
```

This is awesome, but inside the functions, I cannot use `$(this)` to identify the `<form>` from which the submit button was clicked.

Let's say I wrote `alert($(this).attr('id'));` in the **checkRequired()** function. It alerts "**Object, object**".

If I place the same code inside the `$("form").submit()` function, it returns my form's id.

The selectors inside the functions are things like `$("input[type='text']")` and similar, but the functions run on all the inputs, not just the ones in the form that was submitted.

**Sample function() used:**

```
function checkFormats() {

    alert("Checking Formats...");

    $(".email").each(function(){

        alert("Checking Formats: Email...");

        var emailField = $(this).children("input[type='text']");
        var strEmail = emailField.val();

        if( strEmail.indexOf( "@" ) == -1 ) {
            alert("What the hell?");
        }

    });

}
```

I'm sure I'll feel dumb when I hear the solution, but hey, I'm overly-tired lol... Thanks in advance!

**Thinking maybe `$("form",this)` may get me somewhere?**

Comment: try `$("input", $(this))` which will look inside `this` for `input`

Comment: This made the validation stop working... I think the $(this) value is not being passed to the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not pass the form to the methods?

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkRequired(this);
    checkLengths(this);
    checkFormats(this);
    checkErrors(this);
});
```

Then you have the right context.
You can now select any additional elements within the context of the specified form, similar to this::

```
function checkFormats(theForm) {
    $form = $(theForm);

    alert("Checking Formats...");
    
    // Get emails from within the context of the current form.
    $(".email", $form).each(function(){

        alert("Checking Formats: Email...");

        var emailField = $(this).children("input[type='text']");
        var strEmail = emailField.val();

        if( strEmail.indexOf( "@" ) == -1 ) {
            alert("What the hell?");
        }

    });
}
```

---

#### Alternative - Use JavaScript [**.apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

(As mentioned by [**Mike Robinson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43687/mike-robinson) in the comments)

---

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkRequired.apply(this);
    checkLengths.apply(this);
    checkFormats.apply(this);
    checkErrors.apply(this);
});
```

Then `this` within the function becomes the form. You can now use it like this:

```
function checkFormats(theForm) {
    $form = $(this);

    alert("Checking Formats...");
    
    // Get emails from within the context of the current form.
    $(".email", $form).each(function(){

        alert("Checking Formats: Email...");

        var emailField = $(this).children("input[type='text']");
        var strEmail = emailField.val();

        if( strEmail.indexOf( "@" ) == -1 ) {
            alert("What the hell?");
        }

    });
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/czuHW/) - Using `.apply`

---

Demo uses a simple HTML From:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

With this script:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkRequired.apply(this);
});

function checkRequired() {
    alert("This is of type: " + this.nodeName);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be closer to what I'm looking for... I looked up the .apply, but jQuery's documentation is kinda limited? How would I use the .apply here?

Comment: This worked by the way... Thank you! Passing this to the functions (duh) did the trick...

Comment: @derekmx271: I edited the answer to include an example of `.apply`. the reason you won't find it in the jQuery documentation is that it is a JavaScript function. I linked to the mozilla documentation in the edited answer too. I never used it myself but as I understand it it sets the scope of `this` in the called function to what `this` is refering to at the time of the call. Which should be the form. `Mike`: Feel free to correct my statement if I miss-understood it.

Comment: B E A U Tiful! Thanks Francois

Comment: Couldn't get the .apply(this) to work for some reason... Your first suggestion worked great though.

Comment: @derekmx271: Glad you got something to work. Regarding `.apply`, I never used it myself, so  I could have had the syntax wrong. You might need to omit the parenthesis like this: `checkRequired.apply(this);`  instead of this: `checkRequired().apply(this);`

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that later today and maybe post the solution using that :)

Comment: @derekmx271: I played around with `.apply` in a fiddle and yes, it seems you have to omit the `()` of the function. Otherwise in jsFiddle it gave me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` I updated the answer accordingly. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the form an ID and reference that in the jquery call:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
checkRequired();
checkLengths();
checkFormats();
checkErrors();
});
```

Comment: Ya, I know this would do the trick, but I'm trying to avoid using ID's in the .js so the functions can run on all the forms of our site without having to add ID's to the file each time we create a form.

Comment: @derekmx271 so use a class instead, any forms that are in the same class would work. Unless you cant be bothered for that either

Comment: @InGodITrust There's no difference (in terms of the result) in using `$('form')` and `$('.formclass')` if *every* form has that class on it.

Comment: Lol, it's not a bother... Wouldn't applying the same class to all my forms be the same as using simply the <form> tag as the selector?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you would only give this class to the appropriate forms!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is unique name for each form element. Read about jquery selectors where you can select the form you need to select

using Id

$('#form_id')

Class

$('.form1')

or even index within array.

$('form:first')[0] $('form:last')